# DependencyResolutionException Circular component dependency detected: How to use Autofac to inject decorator?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mono, decorator, autofac

I have an interface called `ILastActivityUpdator` as follows:

```
public interface ILastActivityUpdator
{
    void UpdateLastActivity(int userId);
}
```

Besides that I have two classes that implement this interface, being `LastActivityUpdator` and a decorator `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator`. The latter one takes an `ICookieProvider` as extra argument and uses this in the method implementation. I.e.,

```
public LastActivityUpdator(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
    : base(unitOfWork)
{ }

public void UpdateLastActivity(int userId)
{
    // Do some stuff.
}
```

And the decorator:

```
public AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator(
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    ICookieProvider cookieProvider,
    ILastActivityUpdator lastActivityUpdator) 
    : base(unitOfWork)
{
    this.lastActivityUpdator = lastActivityUpdator;
    this.cookieProvider = cookieProvider;
}

public void UpdateLastActivity(int userId)
{
    lastActivityUpdator.UpdateLastActivity(userId);

    cookieProvider.SetCookie(); 
}
```

I want to inject the `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` in `AnonymousUserService` and the `LastActivityUpdator` in `UserService`.

To do this, my RegisterDependencies method in `IoCConfig` contains the following registerings taken from the [Autofac FAQ Decorator section](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators).

builder.RegisterType()
        .Keyed(AuthenticatedStatus.Anonymous)
        .InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType()
        .Keyed(AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated)
        .InstancePerRequest();

```
builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
    .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");

// Then register the decorator. The decorator uses the
// named registrations to get the items to wrap.
builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    (c, p, inner) => new AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator(
        c.Resolve<IOogstplannerUnitOfWork>(), 
        c.Resolve<ICookieProvider>(),
        inner),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator");
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code I get the error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>   Circular component dependency detected:
>  
>   Services.AnonymousUserService ->
>   Services.AnonymousUserService ->
>  
>   Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator ->
>  Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator ->
>  Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator.

Furthermore, I don't see why magically the right implementations would be injected. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because the C# compiler doesn't know which overload of the `RegisterDecorator` method to take.

If you force it :

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    new Func<IComponentContext, ILastActivityUpdator, ILastActivityUpdator>(
        (c, inner) => new AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator(inner)
    ),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator");
```

You will have a new error :

> `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

and this error is caused by this line :

```
new AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator(inner)
```

to resolve this error you have to change the way you create instance of `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator`

for example :

```
// only the type being decorated should be registered here
builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
       .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");

builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    (c, inner) => new AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator(c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>(), 
                                                       c.Resolve<ICookieProvider>(), 
                                                       inner),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator")
       .As<ILastActivityUpdator>();
```

or even better :

```
builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
       .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("lastActivityUpdator");
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
       .Named<ILastActivityUpdator>("anonymousLastActivityUpdator");

builder.RegisterDecorator<ILastActivityUpdator>(
    (c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<ILastActivyUpdator>("anonymousLastActivityUpdator", 
                                                     TypedParameter.From(inner)),
    fromKey: "lastActivityUpdator")
       .As<ILastActivityUpdator>();
```

Comment: The code compiles but when I run it I get the error:

`Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Circular component dependency detected: Services.AnonymousUserService -> Services.AnonymousUserService -> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator -> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator -> Services.AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator. –`

Comment: Ah my bad, Autofac was confused because I registered them earlier when I was scanning the services assembly. The code works! Thanks a lot.